# How do I define a custom mesh in JBullet?

Tags: java, libgdx, bulletphysics

I am creating a game and I wanted to use the JBullet physics engine. I have searched the Javadocs but I have not found anything. How do I define a custom shape to use with JBullet? I was looking for something that I pass the vertices and indices array into, or are there other solutions? Thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ConvexHullShape if your mesh is convex. It takes the vertices as parameter, but doesn't need the indices or other connection information.

For concave mesh you can use BvhTriangleMeshShape. It takes e.g. TriangleIndexVertexArray as a parameter, which is created from lists of triangle indices and vertices.

JBullet is not up-to-date with the latest Bullet versions, but it is still a good physics library for Java.

Comment: Yeah I tried those things and epically failed. I originally wanted to load a heightmap into JBullet. Bullet had a class for exactly that but JBullet didn't. I converted the heightmap into Indices and Vertices and tried this but "it didn't work". I have given up now. I marked this as an answer to my question in the hopes that it might be useful to someone.

Comment: How do I make a TriangleIndexVertexArray take the shape of my model (An  ArrayList of vertices, indices, and faces)?

Comment: @Joehot200 Put the indices and vertices to ByteBuffer and give those to the constructor of TriangleIndexVertexArray. Your faces must be triangles.

Answer (score 0):

JBullet does not seem like complete port, so I moved onto C++ and I am hoping to use Bullet.